# What are the correct jar files for Jzy3d API?

Tags: java, maven, jar, jzy3d

Can someone tell me which .jar files to download to get the newest Jzy3d version? I have looked at their [website](http://www.jzy3d.org) but I don't know which files to download.

Comment: I guess you go to [releases](http://maven.jzy3d.org/releases/org/jzy3d/) and grab every `jar` from sub-folders named `1.0.0` ... or use `maven` to do that for you...

Comment: I tried it and I was able to run demo code (https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/blob/master/jzy3d-tutorials/src/main/java/org/jzy3d/demos/scatter/ScatterDemo.java) from the website. But on other demo code, some methods/classes could not be found. (for example MultiColorScatter although it should exist, according to the documentation (http://doc.jzy3d.org/javadoc/0.8.4/org/jzy3d/plot3d/primitives/MultiColorScatter.html))

Comment: well MultiColorScatter  existed in  `0.8.4` ... but you are using `1.0.0`. and I can't see any MultiColorScatter  there ... though there is a ScatterMultiColor  (http://doc.jzy3d.org/javadoc/1.0.0/jzy3d-api/org/jzy3d/plot3d/primitives/package-summary.html)...

Comment: Replacing MultiColorScatter with ScatterMultiColor solved the problem for me. I guess that the tutorial on their own website is outdated since jzy3d.org still used MultiColorScatter on it (http://www.jzy3d.org/tutorial.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use maven to build Jzy3d charts. [Install maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) if you don't have it.

Add a maven pom.xml file at the root of your project, [similar to this one](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/blob/master/jzy3d-tutorials/pom.xml). Running the following command will import dependencies and build the project

```
mvn clean test install
```

If you want to retrieve jar manually (discouraged), you can get jzy3d builds [here](http://maven.jzy3d.org/releases/org/jzy3d/). You will also have to download jzy3d dependencies (jogl, jply, jmathio, jdt-core, miglayout, opencsv, etc) as listed in [jzy3d-api pom file](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/blob/master/jzy3d-api/pom.xml).

Comment: I'm totally new to developing larger programming projects. Does the maven command have to be run every time before I can run my program? Or does the command run my main program automatically? (Or am I missing something?)

Comment: Yes if you work with command line and text editor. The best is to use an IDE like Eclipse or Intellij.